# Count number of same values in JSON array and convert it to string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

My `JSON` looks something like this:

```
[
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"26","description":"Akita"},
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"6","description":"Pug"},
   {"pet_type":"Cat","weight":"4","description":"Manx"},
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"12","description":"Beagle"},
   {"pet_type":"Cat","weight":"5","description":"Siberian"}
]
```

How could I convert it to a string which would look like`3 Dogs, 2 Cats`?

The way I tried is filling an `array` with `pet_type` and than use `array_count_values` to count number of same records, and later I go through that array in a `foreach` and concat string like this:

```
foreach ($count_animals as $type => $number) {
   $animals .=  $number.' '.str_plural($type, $number).', ';
}
```

This works, but my question is, could I do it with less code, directly from `JSON`, without using one more `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works, you can keep your code.

If you want less code, you can use this version :

```
$json = '[
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"26","description":"Akita"},
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"6","description":"Pug"},
   {"pet_type":"Cat","weight":"4","description":"Manx"},
   {"pet_type":"Dog","weight":"12","description":"Beagle"},
   {"pet_type":"Cat","weight":"5","description":"Siberian"}
]';


print_r(array_count_values(array_map(function($item) {
   return $item['pet_type'];
}, json_decode($json, true))));
```

Gonna display :

```
Array ( [Dog] => 3 [Cat] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
in your controller
$pet = Pet::get();
$petcount = Pet::where('pet_type','Dog')->get();

In your blade
 <h1>{{count($petcount)}} Dog</h1>
```